# SSD Speed Half As Expected

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, speedtest

I have bought a SSD recently. I have checked its speed with several software but speed is only [half as expected](https://consumer.apacer.com/eng/content.php?sn=917).

SSD is installed on SATA 3/6Gb/s and company informed SSD speed is about 550MB/s but I got a speed bellow 300MB/s.
SSD installed on Acer Aspire [AS5742ZG-P613G32Mnkk](https://snlookup.com/acer-aspire-5742zg-notebook-lx-r580c-003-p19631#ffs-tabbed-16)

PC hardware is as listed on the link just HDD replaced by SSD. I use Windows 7 64bit. Here are some screenshots of my measurements:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is a screenshot I found on the web, showing results I would expect:

[image]

Comment: You may find test values in [this review](https://www.tech-critter.com/apacer-as340-panther-240gb-ssd-review/) for comparison. Check also the SMART data of the disk.

Comment: @harrymc it is lower

Comment: You have a 9 years old low cost CPU, therefore I am not surprised that you don't get the full speed.

Answer (score 0):

The data as given by the manufacturer was a bit optimistic, but not by much.
Test results from
[tech-critter.com](https://www.tech-critter.com/apacer-as340-panther-240gb-ssd-review/)
have these measures:

[image]

The numbers for the write tests is perhaps acceptable, but your read is truly about
half speed.

There is a problem with the disk. If the disk is under warranty, you could perhaps
return it.

You could also try the Apacer utilities for the disk, to see if they can throw some
light on the problem, or perhaps update the firmware on the disk.

You may find these utilities on the Apacer website at
[this webpage](https://consumer.apacer.com/eng/content.php?sn=917#function).

Answer (score -1):

Probably a driver to update. Go to [Acer support for Aspire 5742ZG](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/3280?b=1).

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on which drivers to update.